# Broken image retrieved when trying to recuperate it from MySql

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I edited the previous text beacuse I commited a lot of mistakes when coding because of the leak of knowledge in the matter.

I still having a error in the last step "INSERT" in mysqli.

Now this is the frontend

```
<body>
<form action="consulta.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="imagen" id="imagen" placeholder="Subir Foto">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

and this is the backend

```
$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "imagenes") or die("Error en la conexion") or die('error en la seleccion de la bd');
    if (!isset($_FILES['imagen']) || $_FILES['imagen']['error']>0) {
        echo "Ha ocurrido un error";
    }else {
        $permitidos= array("image/jpg","image/jpeg","image/gif","image/png");
        $limite_kb=16384;
        if (in_array($_FILES['imagen']['type'], $permitidos) && $_FILES['imagen']['size'] <=$limite_kb*1024) {
            //Archivo temporal
            $imagen_temporal=$_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
            $tipo=$_FILES['imagen']['type'];
            //leer el archivo temporal en binario
            $data=file_get_contents($imagen_temporal);
            //Escapar los caracteres (Ni idea, tengo que averiguar)
            $data=mysqli_escape_string($conexion,$data);
    mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO imagenes(imagen,tipo_imagen) VALUES('".$data."','".$tipo."')") or die("Error en la carga de imagen");

        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this is how you handle file upload in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php your `enctype` is not correct; you can't just create image from `$_POST`. Also, you're not using `MySQLi` "right": instead of stuffing value into SQL query, you should seriously consider [variable binding](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: Hi Passerby, I followed the things you said me, and I fixed several errors.

So that's because I edited the original post and I put the current code that I'm handling.

I still having a error but is just in the moment of the INSERT with MySqli

I hope this can be more readable than the previous one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure that the field your are inserting to is large enough for the data.  For example, Blob, Text, or something along those lines.  Also, you may want to base64_encode() the file going into the database, and base64_decode() it when reading it from the database.

Comment: Hi Sam, the problem is with the db itself so the problems may be solved with a relative easy, I'm out of the pc but soon I will be in let me check in a couple of hours and I will see if I'm able to solve it.